# Customized back button appears on UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button, uiappearance

I use the following code to customize the back button on the navigation bar throughout my application:

```
UIImage *backButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
UIImage *backButtonOn = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton_on"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonOn
                                                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It's working great except when I present a UIImagePickerController and enter an album in the photo library the back button is also the customized back button. How can I get back the original back button in the image picker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[YourClassThatsNotAUIImagePicker class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:someOtherImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

That should limit your appearance setting to only the classes you list and therefore leave the UIImagePickerController alone.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a custom UINavigationBar subclass and used that in my navigation controller. Then I used the suggested `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationBar class], nil]` method. This way I only had to add my navigation bar class. Was a quick solution, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIImagePickerController class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

this is the correct way

Comment: Definitely the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

1.for swift and ios9(the above answer will be like) --

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIImagePickerController.self]).setBackButtonBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "blank-button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

2.if you want to modify backIndicatorImage of UINavigationBar

```
UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIImagePickerController.self]).backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "backButton")//or nil
```

3.if you want to modify backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage

```
UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIImagePickerController.self]).backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage =UIImage(named: "backButton")// nil
```

Comment: `UINavigationBar` appearance not working when contained in `UIImagePickerController`. `UIBarButtonItem` works ok.