# UIActivityViewController has wrong button title colors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm having a weird issue presenting a UIActivityViewController.

When I present a UIActivityViewController from my application's root view, the button titles are the correct color.

Now, but if I navigate back to the root view controller **from** a detail view controller and present the UIActivityViewController listed above, the presented controller is inheriting the presenting controller's button title colors for some reason. I've tried forcing the bar style to default, but that doesn't work either. Setting the UIActivityViewController's button appearance doesn't work like it does a MFMailComposeViewController.

Any help offered is greatly appreciated! Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Code I'm using to set my detailviewcontroller's button color:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Back";

    UIButton *Button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(heh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonPressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    Button2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44, 44);

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Button2];
}
```

Comment: I don't see where in your code you set the colors. Anyway, could you have a similar problem to this question with appearance customization? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405390/customized-back-button-appears-on-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: I tried the suggested link you gave me, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Edit: it works on MFMailComposeViewController and MFMessageComposeViewController, but not UIActivityViewController

Comment: If I call `[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], [UIViewController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];` It fixes it, but it affects the rest of my app. But if I call `[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], [UIActivityViewController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];`         It doesn't work

Comment: Where do you set the appearance so that it correctly changes the share via Mail and Message button colors? I've tried it in my app delegate and right before displaying the UIActivityViewController and neither work. I still get the default blue iOS 7 buttons. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, I had to manually change my detail view controller's bar button item title colors after dismissing the UIActivityViewController.

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], [UIViewController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, CGSizeMake(0, 0), UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
                                                                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```