# Set appearance of UIImagePickerController back to default

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have made a sublass from `UINavigationController`... Inside this class I set the appearance to the following:

```
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                           [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
                                                           UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"Yellowtail" size:30.0], UITextAttributeFont,
                                                           [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:170/255.0f blue:130/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:170/255.0f blue:130/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Now in my app when I want to take a picture it presents my UIImagePicker but the navigation bar has the same appearance like my custom navigation controllers' navigation bar and the CANCEL button doesn't work...

So my question: How can I use the default iOS style for the image picker and my custom style for the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research I have solved the problem... the solution is quite simple:

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

/* reset the style to the default one */
[picker.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[picker.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:nil];
[picker.navigationBar setBarTintColor:nil];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here someone had the same problem: [Custom nav bar with UIImagePickerControl](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/custom-nav-bar-with-uiimagepickercontrol)

Answer (score 0):

Since your answer appeared first in Google when I searched for this problem, I prefer post a proper answer than the accepted one.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405390/customized-back-button-appears-on-uiimagepickercontroller) treats the problem correctly. `UIAppearance` has a method used for fine UI customization : `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`

As in, for example :

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIImagePickerController class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```